# Validation with validation block

Tags: validation, enterprise-library-5

I need to write a validation with MS enterprise library.
The validation purpose is to validate a string that should have `@` keyword at atleast once and it can have any thing of 120 length, now sure how to do it.

```
  <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.ContainsCharactersValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                 characterSet="@" containsCharacter="Any" name="Contains Characters Validator" />
```

trying something like this but doesn't solve the purpose.

or a regex will work..?

Comment: Is this a function that you are writing?

Comment: No it is MS validation block that checks my model before it passes to backend.

Comment: then C# tag may not be the best one for this question, as you are not actually writing any C# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `ContainsCharactersValidator`, you can use the [`RegexValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.validators.regexvalidator.aspx) with a suitable regular expression.

If your requirements are:

- `@` anywhere in the string, 0 to many instances
- Total string length between 1 and 120 characters
- Other allowed characters are alphanumeric only

Then a regex of `[@A-Za-z0-9]{1,120}` should do the job for you.

Comment: But my requirement is it can have @ at any location more than 1 times and can have any character but limit should have 120

Comment: No problem. Is there a minimum string length requirement? What other characters than are allowed?

Comment: any other character is allowed but it should have @ at-least once and limit should be 120 max

Comment: Is it possible to have both a `RegexValidator` (as I've described) and a `ContainsCharactersValidator` (to verify that there is at least one `@` sign?